# How to check if an input is an int and is between two values

Tags: java, user-input, java.util.scanner

I created a method to see if a value that the user entered is type `int` and is between `liminf` and `limsup`. It returns the value so I can use it as a menu option.
The string `message` tells the user to enter something, and the `error` tells the user to use a number between `limunf` and `limsup`.

My problem is that, for example, if the user enters the number 10 and the `liminf` is 7 and `limsup` e 9, it runs like the number 10 was between `limsup` and `liminf`.

```
public static int readInput(String message, String error, int liminf, int limsup, Scanner rd){

    int option = 0;
    do {
        option = rd.nextInt();
        System.out.println(message);
        while (!rd.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the option");
            rd.nextLine();
        }
        option = rd.nextInt();
        canal.nextLine();
    } while (option > limsup || option < liminf);

    return option;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `option = rd.nextInt()` twice?

Answer (score 2):

When you're checking input, you need to do two things:

1. Check that the value is actually an integer
2. Check that the value is in the range

For checking if a value is an integer, you can use one of two approaches. Use `hasNextInt` on your `Scanner`, or use `Integer.parseInt` and catch `NumberFormatExceptions`. You said in your comments you can't use the second one, so we'll use the first one.

You always have to call `hasNextInt` before you you call `nextInt`, so you can do it like this:

```
int option = 0;
System.out.println(message);
System.out.println("Please enter the option");
while (!rd.hasNextInt()) {
    rd.nextLine(); // Clears the invalid input
    System.out.println("Please enter the option");
}
option = rd.nextInt();
```

This will loop until the user enters an `int`, then it will get that `int`. Note that not calling `hasNextInt` before calling `nextInt` will cause an error, which will happen in your current code if you try to enter a non-number.

Next, you need to do the bounds checking. You want it to be between `limsup` and `liminf`, where `limsup > liminf`,  if I'm not mistaken. We need to determine the condition that will allow this.

*Between* is achieved by using *greater than the lower number and less than the higher number*. In this case, that's `option >= liminf && option <= limsup`. We want to loop when it's *not* this, so we can just wrap the whole thing in `!()`:

```
int option = 0;
do {
    System.out.println(message);
    System.out.println("Please enter the option");
    while (!rd.hasNextInt()) {
        rd.nextLine(); // Clears the invalid input
        System.out.println("Please enter the option");
    }
    option = rd.nextInt();
} while (!(option >= liminf && option <= limsup));

return option;
```

I'll let you figure out how/where to print the error message, but this should get you started.

Worth noting:

- `hasNextInt`, `nextInt`, `nextLine`, etc. will *all wait* for user input if you use `Scanner rd = new Scanner(System.in);`
- Using `nextLine` is necessary to clean out the old input and force the user to enter new input
- While De Morgan's laws are cool, the easiest way to invert a condition is just to wrap it in a `!()`

Answer (score 1):

Change you condition in `while` like this :

```
while (option <= limsup && option >= liminf);
```

With your current condition, when you have `option = 10` and `limsup = 9` then your condition `option > limsup` will evaluate to `true` and as you are using `||` (OR opeartor ) even if the second condition evaluates to `false` the whole expression will evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that if the input is an integer or not with `Integer.parseInt(input);` something like :-

```
 try {

  String s = "a";
  int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
  return true;
  }

catch(NumberFormatException nfe){return false;}
```

and change the condition like:-

```
while (option <= limsup && option >= liminf);
```

Comment: May want to wrap that in a `try...catch` block.

Comment: i'm sure both answers would work, but I can't use it for this assignment due to the fact that I haven't learn any of those suggestions.
Isn't there another way?

Comment: @makoto:- Is that fine now?

Comment: where is the string to convert into `int`. OP is already reading it as int `option = rd.nextInt();`.

Comment: @YogendraSingh:- Just updated my answer. I hope that works now!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you test if a string is an integer:

```
private static boolean isInteger( String s ){

    try{
        Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;
    catch( Exception e ){
        return false;
    }

}
```

However, since you are using the nextInt() function this is not necessary as you will only get integer inputs this way anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((option > limsup) || (option < liminf))
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive, its your `readLine` is making it to ignore the next token(10) itself as its reading the entire line while `hasNextInt` checks the single token. Try simple as below (use `next` and remove the extra `rd.nextInt()` as first statement in your loop):

```
 do {
    System.out.println(message);
    while (!rd.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the option");
        rd.next();
    }
    //now the next token is int
    option = rd.nextInt();
    //flush the new line if any
    rd.nextLine();
} while (option > limsup || option < liminf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your check in the while is wrong (option > limsup || option < liminf)
Look at option > limsup, 10 is bigger then 9 that is why you got this problem